# Android Set url values in RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make an api call to an endpoint like this:

```
http://myapi.co/api/users/23/gifts/2
```

but the viewholder in my adapter is defined like this:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView tvUserName;
    public TextView tvGiftName;

    public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);

        tvUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        tvGiftName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gift_name);
    }
}
```

So each row in my recycler view only shows the user name and the gift name.

```
|---------------------------|
| user name 1   gift name 1 |
|---------------------------|
| user name 1   gift name 3 |
|---------------------------|
| user name 3   gift name 9 |
|---------------------------|
| user name 9   gift name 1 |
|---------------------------|
```

When the item is pressed, it should use the **user id** and **gift id** in order to make another request, but I'm not sure what is the best way to use the id's.

I was wondering if this is the best way to solve my issue:

First add two more text views to each item on my recyclerview list, both of them will have the id of the user and the gift.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView tvUserName;
    public TextView tvUserId;
    public TextView tvGiftName;
    public TextView tvGiftId;

    public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);

        tvUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        tvUserId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_id);
        tvGiftName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gift_name);
        tvGiftId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gift_id);

    }
}
```

And make the text of the Id textviews blank (in order for both of them not to appear on screen), so when I need to create the url I'd do something like this:

```
url = "http://myapi.co/api/users/" + tvUserId.getText() + 
      "/gifts/" + tvUserId.getText();
```

Is this the right approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post where do you get te values of each text

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to use [Uri.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html)

example :

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("https")
      .authority("myapi.co/api/users/")
      .appendPath(tvUserId.getText())
      .appendPath(tvUserId.getText());
String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

Comment: My recyclerview item only shows USERNAME and GIFTNAME, should I add the USER_ID and GIFT_ID in order to create that url?

Comment: no, you can easily pass the id as a Tag by this way 
tvUserName.setTag(USER_ID);
tvGiftName.setTag(ID);

and get them in this way 
tvUserName.getTag().toString();